# How to make vim mode in vs code work with other languages?

Tags: vscode

I use English(US) and Russian layouts on my laptop. I wonder, is there a way to configure the vim extension in vs code so that it works normally with other languages? I want all commands and mode switching to work in Russian layout.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Note to others: [help/on-topic](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says *Questions about plugins that replicate Vim's editing model in other editors (VSCode, Sublime Text, Emacs, etc.) may be on topic if they are about features or behavior that also exists in Vi or its derivatives, as discussed in the meta question linked to, above.*

Comment: did you find out how?

Comment: @ZenVentzi no..